Class not registered when trying to run MAUI App
I am trying to run a MAUI app that was running on a another computer which I cannot access now, but it is not running on my current laptop.
The error I get is before initializing.
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
  HResult=0x80040154
  Message=Class not registered (0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode)
   at WinRT.ActivationFactory.Get(String typeName)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ApplicationModel.WindowsAppRuntime.DeploymentInitializeOptions.get__objRef_global__Microsoft_Windows_ApplicationModel_WindowsAppRuntime_DeploymentInitializeOptions()
   at Microsoft.Windows.ApplicationModel.WindowsAppRuntime.DeploymentInitializeOptions..ctor()
   at Microsoft.Windows.ApplicationModel.WindowsAppRuntime.DeploymentManagerCS.AutoInitialize.get_Options() in C:\Users\Eneko\.nuget\packages\microsoft.windowsappsdk\1.6.240923002\include\DeploymentManagerAutoInitializer.cs:line 44
   at Microsoft.Windows.ApplicationModel.WindowsAppRuntime.DeploymentManagerCS.AutoInitialize.AccessWindowsAppSDK() in C:\Users\Eneko\.nuget\packages\microsoft.windowsappsdk\1.6.240923002\include\DeploymentManagerAutoInitializer.cs:line 30
   at .cctor()

I tried installing the Windows App SDK x64 version.
Also tried reinstalling the C++ redistributable.
Image of the failure in Visual Studio
Does anyone know how to solve it?

NET MAUI does not currently support using Windows App SDK controls. If you have existing controls from other Windows App SDK projects you intend to re-use or rely on 3rd Party or open source controls, you will need to find alternatives for .NET MAUI projects.
